# Jetpack Compose Swipe right to go back

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

How to use JC to swipe back to the right, similar to the following effect:

Most likely to utilize the [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/navigation-animation/) library, since it includes animations and just need to add gestures

[image]

Comment: Did you ever get this working in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: @Daniel No, there is no way to solve it yet

Comment: For Wear OS back swipe https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/compose/navigation worked for me

Comment: @AlexeyKolosov Does it apply to mobile phones? can you provide a demo

Comment: @AlexeyKolosov while using this im getting this error    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The WearNavigator backstack is empty, there is no navigation destination to display.

Comment: @MubashirMurtaza Do you use it like this:
        `setContent { ...`
   `val navController = rememberSwipeDismissableNavController()`
   `SwipeDismissableNavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "screen1") {`
   ` composable("screen1") { Screen1() }`
   ` composable("screen2") { Screen2() }`
?

Comment: @AlexeyKolosov , now its working, there were 2 libraries in gradle for navigation so i was importing some functions form the other one thats way it was not working...
thanks

Comment: @MubashirMurtaza Heard yours is working, could you please contribute an answer to this question?

Comment: @gaohomway i would love to but I'm working on wear OS, I don't think so this Quest is about wear OS, as of my knowledge there is not lib from android yet to achieve this behaviour on Phone OS  ..

Comment: Did anyone figure this out?